# Firestick get application binary

Tags: android

I would like to reverse engineer and ultimately patch an application on my Amazon Firestick. To doo this, I want to analyze the app executable.

I believe third-party apk's are stored in the `/data` directory but this directory is not readable on an unrooted device. I've also considered dumping the process memory while the app is running, but I believe this would also require rooting the device. I would prefer to not root the device if possible but I understand that might be necessary.

Does anyone know of a way I can get the application binary without rooting the device?

Comment: All rooting does is get you access to the root account. If you want to do _anything_ that you're not explicitly allowed by e.g. the file's permissions, you're going to need to root it. This might not even be hard or even unsupported, necessarily; there are plenty of consumer devices (besides the obvious ones) that are meant to be rootable, especially for developers. You could always dig through Amazon's documentation to see -- maybe have a look at their developer resources? I'd imagine they have _some_ provision for deploying to a Firestick, which might have the answers you need.

Comment: I think you're right that I will need to root the device. However, it seems to me that rooting the Firestick is tricky. For my version of the firmware, the most prevalent method involved shorting a circuit on the board. The developer docs only provide options for monitoring resource usage.

Answer (score 3):

`adb shell pm list packages -f` should list all of the installed packages, as well as the path to their apk. Find the apk you're interested in, then pull it with `adb pull <path>`.

e.g.

```
> adb shell pm list packages -f
....
package:/data/app/com.google.android.dialer-nt9PJ8MFE293dEV61etgIA==/base.apk=com.google.android.dialer
....
> adb pull /data/app/com.google.android.dialer-nt9PJ8MFE293dEV61etgIA==/base.apk
```

Comment: This doesn't require rooting?

Comment: I just tried this and it allows me to "download" the directory but it is empty.

Comment: I added a more specific example. You should be able to pull the apk file itself, not the directory

Answer (score 2):

I came across this forum thread that had the correct solution: https://forum.xda-developers.com/fire-tv/help/extract-apk-t3674633. The solution was to download ESFile Explorer and backup the app for which I was seeking the APK. I could then run `adb pull /storage/emulated/0/backups/app/<my app>`.